# Server occasionally "Forbidden - You don't have permission to access this resource"

Tags: php, http-status-code-403

My server scripts are in PHP and data is stored in MySQL, and things work fine locally on my computer when pages are served by MAMP.
However, when deployed on an AWS server or two other hosting services that I've tried, I **occasionally** get this error when clicking on internal links (links that point to pages in my websites):

[image]

This error seems to occur randomly, in that I haven't found any discernible pattern as to under what circumstances this error typically pops up.

On average, out of every 20-30 clicks that I hit, I get this error once, and the only way to make it work is to hit the back button in the browser and follow the link again (simply refreshing the page doesn't work as it results in the same error).